# Difference between LongWord and Cardinal in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, constants, delphi-xe, typed

This code doesn't compile in XE :

```
const
    InitSignature : array[0..3] of LongWord =
        ($67452301, $EFCDAB89, $98BADCFE, $10325476);
```

[DCC Error]: E2026 Constant expression expected

but this DOES:

```
const
    InitSignature : array[0..3] of Cardinal =
    ($67452301, $EFCDAB89, $98BADCFE, $10325476);
```

Assignable typed constants is ON.

If I cast all the array values to LongWord in the first sample the code compiles.
But I cannot get what's the difference between LongWord and Cardinal?

Comment: Compiles fine in D2007. According to the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Simple_Types), there still shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: Agreed, there should be no difference and even when the 64 bit version comes out there will still be no difference.

Comment: It's a compatibility thing. Really Integer/Cardinal should be machine independant but iirc they're fixed so LongWord is 64-bit and Cardinal is 32-bit :/

Comment: According to the docs Cardinal is 32-bit no-sign and LongWord is also 32-bit no-sign. So it should be compatible. Interestingly it also says "type LongWord = 0..-1;" and "type Cardinal = 0..4294967295;". Somewhere LongWord is mentioned as an alias for Cardinal.

Comment: I would file a QC entry, because it looks they made an error. Longword, should be a DWORD and declared like Cardinal, not 0..-1.

Comment: Works just fine for me in Delphi XE with update 1 installed.

Comment: @Llyod: `LongWord` is not 64-bit, and won't be 64-bit in the upcoming 64-bit compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to be bold, and state ***there is *no* difference***. You arrived at the wrong conclusion somehow, and provided us with not enough information to help you out. I'm convinced you didn't paste a 1:1 copy of your code here, and you left out something relevant.

Could be an evil workmate who pasted a little inivisble unicode character before the opening parenthesis, and defined that same character as a function elsewhere. It could also be something a little more obvious.

Can you reproduce the issue in a clean project? Because I'm pretty sure you can't. If you can, post back. If you can't, post more context. By all means, prove me wrong.

Comment: Or else the OP just needs to install Rad XE update 1, which fixed a problem. Or else the OP is using code with lovely function names like function LongWord:Boolean;

Answer (score 1):

You might have a function called longword somewhere in your code.

```
function LongWord: Integer;
begin
 result := 0;
end;

procedure Foo;
const
    InitSignature : array[0..3] of LongWord =
        ($67452301, $EFCDAB89, $98BADCFE, $10325476);
begin
  //...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below compiles fine in Delphi XE.

Show us more context of your code; it looks like something redefines `LongWord` for you.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
  InitSignatureLongWords : array[0..3] of LongWord =
    ($67452301, $EFCDAB89, $98BADCFE, $10325476);

const
  InitSignatureCardinals : array[0..3] of Cardinal =
    ($67452301, $EFCDAB89, $98BADCFE, $10325476);

begin
end.
```

--jeroen

Comment: It would have to be an AWESOME redefinition to trigger "constant expression expected". The closest guess I'd come up with is defining it as a 4-argument function, then somehow forgetting to type the equals sign. Perhaps a record with an assignment operator will do the trick?